# Find template parameters at runtime

Tags: c++, templates

it's possible to have access to template "type", for instance in the std

```
std::vector<int>::size_type
```

is it possible to have the same thing for objects passed as template parameters?
For instance:

```
template<int i>
class A {
//?
};

A<3> instance;
int number = instance::???? //<--- assigns 3 to number
```

is it possible to get the 3 passed in the object type again at runtime? Without creating a specific member in the A class (which would increase the size of the object)

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of the variable is known to the compiler at compile time, it's just a matter of getting it to give it up.

```
template<int i>
int get(const A<i> & instance)
{
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
template<int i>
class A { 
public:
  enum { number = i };
};

int main() {
  A<3> instance;
  std::cout << instance.number;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make it `static`, it's certainly not changing per-instance. Your solution increases the size of the class, a scenario explicitly forbidden in the question.

Comment: this should not change the size

Comment: Your new version, yes, the old one, no.

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted one.  The accepted one might very well add a bunch of extra, pointless functions to the executable when optimizations aren't right.  This version adds nothing.